Create table without using pivot table functionality with google sheets
How can I turn the following live data (collected via a linked google form) about purchases made:



Timestamp
Price
Specific Category
DateVal
Date
Year
DayOfWeek




4/15/2024 13:49:34
200
Gifts
45397
15/04
2024
Mon


4/15/2024 13:49:44
65
Dinner
45397
15/04
2024
Mon


4/16/2024 13:49:54
14
Lunch
45398
16/04
2024
Tue


4/16/2024 13:50:02
5
Snacks
45398
16/04
2024
Tue


4/16/2024 14:50:02
3
Snacks
45398
16/04
2024
Tue


4/17/2024 13:50:18
8
Transport
45399
17/04
2024
Wed


4/17/2024 13:50:25
14
Snacks
45399
17/04
2024
Wed


4/18/2024 13:50:36
14
Breakfast
45400
18/04
2024
Thu


4/18/2024 13:50:42
15
Lunch
45400
18/04
2024
Thu


4/19/2024 13:50:50
19
Dinner
45401
19/04
2024
Fri


4/20/2024 13:51:00
7
Materials
45402
20/04
2024
Sat


4/20/2024 13:51:09
5
Snacks
45402
20/04
2024
Sat


4/21/2024 13:51:22
30.8
Lunch
45403
21/04
2024
Sun


4/21/2024 13:51:33
8
Snacks
45403
21/04
2024
Sun



into a table that looks like the following in google sheets, without using the pivot table functionality?

Importantly:

the table would need to update whenever the data updates
the value for each cell should be the sum of the spending in the corresponding category for the corresponding day (e.g. $5 and $3 were spent on snacks on 16/4, so the total is reported as $8)
as new days are added to the data, they would be added to the table as well
as new categories are added to the data, they would be added to the table

I am new to google sheets/excel so an explanation of any potential solutions would be appreciated (I have a decent amount of programming experience so doesn't have to be super detailed).

This is doable using the QUERY function. Please provide the example data as a markdown table within your question as this will make it easier for someone to provide an answer.

Ok done. Yeah I expected it to be some form of QUERY or ARRAYFORMULA function, but just can't figure it out.

Have a go with this:
=ArrayFormula(let(
liveData,{A:C,weeknum(A:A,2)},
pvt,transpose(query(liveData,"select toDate(Col1),sum(Col2) where toDate(Col1) is not null and Col3 is not null group by toDate(Col1) pivot Col3 label toDate(Col1) 'Specific category' format toDate(Col1) 'yyyy-mm-dd'",1)),
dow,iferror(if(to_date(chooserows(pvt,1)),text(chooserows(pvt,1),"ddd"),)),
dayTtl,{"TOTALS",chooserows(query(liveData,"select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null and Col3 is not null pivot Col1",1),2)},
wkTtlHlp,query(liveData,"select max(Col1),sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null and Col3 is not null group by Col4 label max(Col1) 'Specific category', sum(Col2) 'WEEKLY TOTALS'",1),
wkTtl,ifna(vlookup(chooserows(pvt,1),wkTtlHlp,2,0)),
catTtl,query(liveData,"select sum(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col3 label sum(Col2) 'CATEGORY TOTAL'",1),
{{"";catTtl;"";""},{dow;pvt;dayTtl;wkTtl}}))

Use this is a different tab to your live data, and change the references in the liveData variable from 'Source' (used as a placeholder here) to point to whatever you've named the actual tab where your form data arrives. I'm ignoring the DateVal/Date/Year/DayOfWeek columns in your source as (I'm assuming) they are calculated from formulas alongside the form data.
I'm not going to explain it all, but we are basically creating the different elements of the table separately and then stacking them together at the end.
EDIT
Formula tweaked to ensure grouping by date, and category totals added

This is amazing. Thank you!
I had to make a minor modification in using Col4 (DateVal) instead of Col1 (Timestamp), because otherwise transactions on the same day at different times weren't grouped.
Also on a side note, is there an easy way to add row sums to this? Perhaps between the Specific category column and the first date?

Have a try with the updated formula I've just posted. It should ensure grouping by date now without needing to refer to your additional Col4 (by using ToDate within the main QUERY to strip the time part away from the timestamps). I've added row sums to the left of the category column (inserting them between the category column and first date is much harder to do than this option)

I had some issues with the weekly totals with this method. I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. The problem was fixed when using the Col4 that I had added though. Erros is: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 18. Was expecting: ")"

Difficult to further diagnose without seeing your sheet. If you've got it working with your additional DateVal column though, and are otherwise happy, feel free to post your changes here and I'll integrate them back into the answer.

liveData,{'sht'!B:D,weeknum('sht'!D:D,2)}, pvt,transpose(query(liveData,"select Col3,sum(Col1) where Col3 is not null and Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col2 label Col3 'Category' format Col3 'dd/mm'",1)), dayTtl,{"",chooserows(query(liveData,"select sum(Col1) where Col3 is not null and Col2 is not null pivot Col3",1),2)}, wkTtlHlp,query(liveData,"select max(Col3),sum(Col1) where Col3 is not null and Col2 is not null group by Col4 label max(Col3) 'Category', sum(Col1) ''",1), catTtl,query(liveData,"select sum(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 label sum(Col1) 'Amount'",1)

^ Those are the only variables which are affected by the changes
